# Given tuple type of string constants and tuple type of other types, create object type with string keys and value types

Tags: typescript

I've been thinking about how to specify types for something like [daggy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daggy), where you specify a list of property names in an array and it creates some constructors.

Essentially, I think want something like this:

```
[A, B] with [X, Y] => { [A]: X, [B]: Y }
```

where `A` and `B` are arbitrary string-constant-types and `X` and `Y` are any types.  e.g.

```
['x', 'y'] with [string, number] => { x: string, y: number }
```

Given the target use of [daggy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daggy), the target interface would likely end up something like

```
<K0 extends string, K1 extends string>(keys: [K0, K1])
  => <V0, V1>(v0: V0, v1: V1)
    => { [K0]: V0, [K1]: V1 }
```

One thing I noticed that is somewhat close which does work is that TS seems to accept `[K in NS[number]: ...` and `[K in K0|K1]` as valid.  The following works as expected:

```
function point<
  A extends string,
  B extends string
>(names: [A, B]): { [K in A|B]: number };
function point(names: any[]): { [x: string]: number } {
  return {
    [names[0]]: 0,
    [names[1]]: 0,
  };
}

const p0 = point(['a', 'b']);
// :: { a: number, b: number }
```

However, in this case, you can't assume the order of iteration over the members of the union, and there's no way to zip those members together with the members of another union.

But if I try to use a `K extends string` type directly, like this:

```
function createZip2Object<
  K0 extends string,
  K1 extends string
>(names: [K0, K1]): <V0, V1>(v0: V0, v1: V1) => { [K0]: V0, [K1]: V1 };
function createZip2Object(names: [string, string]): { [x: string]: any } {
  return (...args) => ({
    [names[0]]: args[0],
    [names[1]]: args[1],
  });
}

const point = createZip2Object(['x', 'y']);
const p0 = point(10, 945);
```

I get the messages `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.` and `'K0' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

This error message appears even with simpler examples that don't try to hide type parametrizations in inner functions:

```
function boxValue<K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V): { [K]: V } {
  return { [k]: v };
}

const bv = boxValue('v', 42);
// :: {}
```

This happens on the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) and in VSCode with Typescript 2.9.1.

I know I could just manually specify the type of the stuff returned by daggy's constructor creators, but I wanted to know if there was a more general way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an intersection type and mapped typed to create the objects you want:

```
function createZip2Object<
    K0 extends string,
    K1 extends string
    >(names: [K0, K1]): <V0, V1>(v0: V0, v1: V1) => { [P in K0]: V0 } & { [P in K1]: V1 };
function createZip2Object(names: [string, string]): { [x: string]: any } {
    return (...args: any[]) => ({
        [names[0]]: args[0],
        [names[1]]: args[1],
    });
}

const point = createZip2Object(['x', 'y']);
const p0 = point(10, 945);
```

Comment: That's definitely pretty funky, and the signature of the resultant object still shows as an intersection of course, but it does give me the proper property suggestions with their types in VSCode, which is what I need.